# Why does my exFAT USB drive need repair whenever I accidentally unplug it?

Tags: external-hard-drive, filesystems, filesystem-corruption, exfat

Whenever I accidentally unplug my USB exFAT drive without ejecting it first, it either becomes read-only or disappears altogether from my file system when I plug it back in. I have to run a repair cycle on it in Disk Utility before it starts working again. This never happened with my FAT32 or NTFS drives. What's going on? Does this mean that exFAT less safe for external use? Or is it simply a quirk unique to my system?

Answer (score 1):

Different file-systems are more or less tolerant to data-loss.  Most modern file-systems have what is called [journaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system) which means that if the connection between the computer and storage is unexpectedly severed then when the file-system is eventually remounted then the data that wasn't successfully written can be "played back" on the file-system.  This automatically recovers from a class of error.  Whatever the file-system, unexpectedly disconnecting the device can always lead to information loss.  With different systems being more or less tolerant of that.

Comment: Yes — but I've read many comments (including on this site) that say that exFAT is better suited to USB drives than NTFS or FAT32, which is why I'm a bit confused. Surely a FS with journaling would be much better suited to that purpose?

Comment: exFAT is a relatively new file-system and used primarily for mobile devices.  If I was using USB drives in a Windows or Windows/Linux mix I'd use NTFS as the file-system.  NTFS is fully supported under Windows, obviously, and also supported under Linux with "NTFS-3g" installed.  NTFS is a mature file-system and tolerant of errors so that is why I would choose it.  Some devices however must use exFAT so depending on what you actually own your choices may have to be different.

Comment: NTFS is generally bad for USB disks because the NTFS driver for windows **is not designed for removable drives** and does not properly handle a number of use-cases were the user might unplug the drive and reattach it later, which can lead to corrupted data. Also, most non-Windows OSes do not have out-of-the-box support for writing to NTFS drives. FAT is generally considered bad because it has no journaling and a max file size of 4GiB. exFAT is slightly better than FAT in that it doesn't have the 4GiB limit, but it's still not journaled.

Comment: As long as you eject your NTFS USB drives there should be no issues.  I've never had issues with it and I've used it for years on USB thumb-drives.

Comment: Sounds like there's no perfect format for portable drives. :(

Comment: @DarthAndroid - Windows makes it extremly easy to eject a disk the proper way, and you should do this, no matter wha the filesystme is anyways.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, yes you should. NTFS will not properly handle if you say, sleep the computer, remove the drive, change something, reconnect the drive, and then wake up the computer. That will corrupt your NTFS drive, whereas that won't corrupt a FAT drive.

Comment: True I don't remove devices unless I know I safely removed it personally served me well never had a corrupt file on a flash drive in a decade and a half

Comment: You don't want journaling on flash drives because they have a finite lifetime in terms of the number of writes; non-essential writes should be avoided on them.